# What python function returns the sorting array which permutes one unique array into another form?

Tags: python, function, sorting, vectorization, permutation

How can I find the array that permutes one array into another? In particular, I'm looking for a vectorized magic function that takes two unique but permuted arrays as input, and returns the ordering array to permute one to the other. For example:

```
>>> x1 = np.array([3, 1, 4, 2])
>>> x2 = np.array([2, 1, 3, 4])
>>> sort = magic_function(x1,x2) # such that x1[sort] == x2
>>> print(sort)
array([3, 1, 0, 2])
>>> print(x1[sort])
array([2, 1, 3, 4])
```

While the function

```
def find_permutation(x1,x2):
  report = np.zeros_like(x1)
  for ii in range(len(x1)):
    report[ii] = np.argwhere(x1==x2[ii])
  return report
```

works, it isn't vectorized, because of the for loop, so it won't cut it for me.

Comment: [`np.argsort()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html)?

Comment: `argsort` would sort the whole array, not sort one array into another... I was thinking of doing argsort on both, then figure out how to go from one sorting to the other, but that didn't seem the simplest path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
sort = x1.argsort()[x2.argsort().argsort()]
```

It works by establishing a common mapping to the sorted values and using the indices to build the (reversed) indirection:

```
common mapping:      1, 2, 3, 4
x1 [3, 1, 4, 2] ==> [1, 3, 0, 2] x1.argsort()
x2 [2, 1, 3, 4] ==> [1, 0, 2, 3] x2.argsort().argsort()
                     |  |  |  |
                     v  v  v  v
indirection (sort): [3  1  0  2] x1.argsort()[x2.argsort().argsort()]
                    [2, 1, 3, 4] x1[sort] == x2
```

[EDIT] second example added because 1st example produced same array for `x2.argsort()` and `x2.argsort().argsort()` which lead to an incomplete/incorrect answer :

```
common mapping:      1, 2, 3, 4
x1 [3, 1, 2, 4] ==> [1, 2, 0, 3] x1.argsort()
x2 [4, 1, 2, 3] ==> [3, 0, 1, 2] x2.argsort().argsort()
                     |  |  |  |
                     v  v  v  v
indirection :       [3, 1, 2, 0] sort
                    [4, 1, 2, 3] x1[sort] == x2
```

*This is vectorized, works even if x1 contains duplicate values, and has complexities of O(N) space and O(NlogN) time*

This could be written as an assignment, so that it only performs 2 sorts instead of 3:

```
sort = np.zeros_like(x1)
sort[x2.argsort()] =  x1.argsort()

all(x1[sort] == x2) # True
```

Comment: As written, this doesn't work; if you have `x1=[3, 1, 2, 4]` and `x2=[4, 1, 2, 3]`, then `sort = x1.argsort()[x2.argsort()]` gives `[2, 0, 3, 1]`, so `x1[sort] != x2`.

Comment: But going off of your answer, you and use the argsort of an argsort: 
`x1[np.argsort(x1)][np.argsort(np.argsort(x2))] == x2`
and that always works. The logic being that the two outside argsorts get the two into a comparable list, while the middle argsort permutes x1 into x2. Or written your way, just adding in a second argsort: 
`sort = x1.argsort()[x2.argsort().argsort()]`

Comment: I corrected my answer and added your second example.  In the original example, `x2.argsort()` produced the same result as `x2.argsort().argsort()` which mislead me into believing the second argsort() wasn't needed (my bad).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution I could come up with was the following function:

```
def find_permutation(x1,x2):
  return np.argwhere(x1[None,:] == x2[:,None])[:,1]
```

The code essentially finds the sorting matrix `M = x1[None,:] == x2[:,None]` for which `np.dot(M,x1) == x2`, then finds which (`argwhere`) columns (`[:,1]`) are filled, returning then the array of indices which sort `x1` into `x2`.

Comment: This will produce a larger output than the input when there are duplicate values in the arrays.

Comment: Good point; this would require x1 and x2 to be unique.